# Entity Framework error when adding a new entity to a DbSet

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, savechanges

I have the following problem :

I created a class `Actual`. This is the mapping to the table:

```
    ToTable("actuals");
    HasKey(x => x.Id);
    Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("actuals_sk");
    ...;
    Property(x => x.PersonId).HasColumnName("actuals_by_sk");
    Property(x => x.AssignmentId).HasColumnName("evaluation_task_id");
    Property(x => x.JobCodeId).HasColumnName("job_cd_sk");
    Property(x => x.ProjectId).HasColumnName("is_sk");
```

Now when I do a `DbSet.Add(entity)` where the entity is the `actual` instance, I keep  getting the same error :

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'person_sk', table 'aariworx_app.dbo.person'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Now the strange thing is, that I provide all the necessary entities when mapping the properties.

```
 Person person = new Person() 
                     { Id = 77, 
                       Name = actualVM.Person.Name, 
                       CreationDate = new DateTime(2014, 02, 04, 19, 53, 08, 000), 
                       User = actualVM.Person.UserName, 
                       Active = 1, 
                       ContractHrs = 38, 
                       ContractDays = Convert.ToDecimal("5,00"), 
                       HoursFullDay = Convert.ToDecimal("7,60"), 
                       HoursHalfDay = Convert.ToDecimal("3,80"), 
                       MaxMoreHours = 80, 
                       WarnMoreHours = 70, 
                       Freelancer = 0, 
                       AuthMethod = Model.Utils.AuthMethod.AD,  
                       EmailSend = 0, 
                       HourlyCost = 45 };
        Assignment assignment = new Assignment() { Id = 3, Description = "Projectleiding", DTS = new DateTime(2006, 1, 5, 18, 30, 6, 000) };
        JobCode jobCode = new JobCode() { Id = actualVM.JobCode.JobCodeId, Description = actualVM.JobCode.Description, CostCenter = 10, CostType = "F", LongDescription = "Ontwikkeling van de aariXa-website", Closed = 0, Date = new DateTime(2007, 5, 16, 2, 23, 12, 000) };
        Project project = new Project() { Id = actualVM.Project.ProjectId, Description = actualVM.Project.Project, Date = new DateTime(2007, 5, 16, 2, 23, 12, 000) };

        return new Actual()
        {
            Id = actualVM.Id,
            ...,
            Assignment = assignment ,
            AssignmentId = assignment.Id,
            JobCode = jobCode,
            JobCodeId = jobCode.Id,
            Project = project,
            ProjectId = project.Id,
            Person = person,
            PersonId = person.Id                
        };
```

So I don't know what is going wrong.

When I look at the queries that are being performed, there is an INSERT for person happening, which I don't need, since the person already exists.

Can anyone help me?

I noticed that when I do the savechanges to save my "actual" to the database, that the following query is also executed and I don't understand why :

```
INSERT [dbo].[person]([name], [user], [person_DTS], [pwd], [active_yn], [contract_hrs], [contract_days], [hours_full_day], [hours_half_day], [max_more_hours], [warn_more_hours], [freelancer_yn], [auth_method], [email_sent], [artikel_aarifact], [Uurkost]) 
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, NULL, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, NULL, @13) 

SELECT [person_sk] 
FROM [dbo].[person] 
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [person_sk] = scope_identity()
```

And since I'm passing the Id of the person, I don't see why the query should by using `scope_identity()`

Comment: An "Actual" is just a table in my database. It contains hours somebody worked on a specific project doing a specific task.

Comment: Ok, got one step closer. now the first thing I do is get the person from the database. Then I add that to my instance of Actual. Now it almost works . I get the error that I cannot insert NULL in the actuals_sk which is defined as key. I even get that same error when I pass a value to the ID.

Comment: turn off DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity for your column "person_sk"